# How does Sails.js work on heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, sails.js

I've created a simple app with Sails.js and deployed it to Heroku, it works fine.
Here is my `Procfile`:

```
web: sails lift
```

But on Heroku (as I think) there is no binary `sails` installed, so how does it work?

**UPDATE**:

I've removed `main` and `start` sections from `package.json` in case `npm start` command is used, but the app still runs fine.
Also I've added `--prod` option in Procfile and it is treated correctly.

Here are `git push` output (no warn/err about Procfile)

```
-----> Node.js app detected

   PRO TIP: Specify a node version in package.json
   See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support

-----> Defaulting to latest stable node: 0.10.28
-----> Downloading and installing node
-----> Restoring node_modules directory from cache
-----> Pruning cached dependencies not specified in package.json
-----> Writing a custom .npmrc to circumvent npm bugs
-----> Exporting config vars to environment
-----> Installing dependencies
-----> Caching node_modules directory for future builds
-----> Cleaning up node-gyp and npm artifacts
-----> Building runtime environment
-----> Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing... done, 19.3MB
-----> Launching... done, v8
```

and `heroku logs` (process is started with `sails lift --prod` command, not `node app.js`)

```
Slug compilation started
Slug compilation finished
Deploy 35bcbd9 by ...
Release v8 created by ..
Unidling
State changed from down to starting
Starting process with command `sails lift --prod`
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
Warning: connection.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
info:    Sails.js           <|
info: 
info:                       /|.\
info:    v0.9.16             |\
info:                 `--'-------' 
info:                      / || \
info:                 .-'.-==|/_--'
info:    __---___--___---___--___---___--___
info:                    ,'  |'  \
info: To see your app, visit http://localhost:3661

debug: --------------------------------------------------------
info: Server lifted in `/app`
info:  ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__
info: 
info: To shut down Sails, press <CTRL> + C at any time.
info: 
debug: :: Sat May 17 2014 09:37:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
debug: 
debug: Environment : production
debug: --------------------------------------------------------
debug: Port        : 3661
State changed from starting to up
```

Comment: Did you go over https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs ?

Comment: Yes, I don't see where you're leading to...

Comment: My guess (which is why I didn't mark it as an answer) is that if it indeed doesn't have sails installed globally, it uses/tries `npm start` since it exists, which runs `node app.js`.

Comment: @CWSpear, seems like it's not the case - I've removed `start` section from `package.json` and everything is working ok. See update

Answer (score 0):

Is my understanding that heroku takes binaries from node_modules and add them to the path (or something like that.

Another option is that perhaps your Procfile is not being taken into account (like if it is misplaced or something wrong with it), then it will default to "npm start", which probably in your package.json redirects to "node app.js" (instead of the sails binary).

In my case, I don't have Profile, and it works ok, but I don't know if it defaults to "npm start" or is codeship.io (my build system) who is telling heroku to do so (I touched no configuration at all).

**UPDATE**: According to heroku documentation (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support),

> The following environment variables will be set:
>   PATH=vendor/node/bin:bin:node_modules/.bin:$PATH

That node_modules/.bin stuff could do the trick :)

Comment: Hi, please see update. Seems like `npm start` is not run. Maybe Heroku does actually have sails installed?